# Errorlog sql server error login failed for user sa. reason: passord dit not match that for the login... [client: xx.xx.xx.xx]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I saw my server. The error log file is big size.
I do not know, I have misconfigured or be sent more request to check my account "SA". SQl write log 1 row ever second with same ip client, CPU of SQL server window NT service is high (80%).

I have a few question:

1. Does my server have ddos sql attack?
2. How way to reduce write log  login failed?
3. If server attack to find my account . how to way limit IP client for request check  my account ?

this is error log:

```
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.47 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.47 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 45.252.80.5]
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.55 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.55 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 45.119.9.117]
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.67 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.67 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 45.119.9.117]
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.76 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.76 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 45.119.9.117]
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.82 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
    2020-01-19 16:28:39.82 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 45.119.15.184]
...
```

Comment: The better question is why do you not have a firewall blocking access from external hosts apart from specific IPs, or why have your port open to external hosts to start with. This isn't a DDOS attack, this is something trying to brute force their way into your server. Take it off the WAN, fix the firewall, then put it back on (if you must).

Comment: Yes.  At a minimum turn on the Windows Firewall and add a rule to allow access to your SQL Server port only from specific IP addresses or ranges.  And make sure SA is disabled `alter login sa disable`, and have a create sysadmin login for you to use.